# Two-sided Jacobi SVD vs One-sided Jacobi SVD

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

In both algorithms we're applying a sequence of Jacobi rotations $J_n$ to implicitly diagonalize $A^TA:$ $$J_n^T...J_1^TA^TAJ_1...J_n=\Sigma \iff (AJ_1...J_n)^T(AJ_1...J_n) =\Sigma \iff (AV)^T AV = \Sigma \\
\iff U^TAV=\Sigma$$ So what's the difference between Two-sided Jacobi SVD vs One-sided Jacobi SVD?